# dataEvents and .change() method not working in jqgrid/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have one jqgrid with two below columns, **Owner** and **NotifyUsers**. **NotifyUser** depends on value of **Owner** column. Like Conutry -> State -> city.

```
 {name:'owner',index:'owner',width:80,hidden:false,search:false,align:'center',
        edittype:'select',editable:true},

{name:'notifyUsers',index:'notifyUsers',width:100,hidden:false,search:false,align:'center',
    edittype:'select',editable:true,editoptions:{ value:'${notifiedUserList}', multiple: true}},
```

I am doing Form Editing. When we select any row I have below code to populate both these SelectBox.

```
 ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {               
        $("#searchcriteraigrid").setColProp('owner', {editoptions:{dataUrl:'getUserList.html?critId=' + rowid}});
        $("#searchcriteraigrid").setColProp('notifyUsers', {editoptions:{dataUrl:'getNotifiedUSerList.html?critId=' + rowid, multiple: true}});
)};
```

There is no problem upto this.

But I need to populate **NotifyUsers** dropdown based on the value of **Owner** Drop down.

I tried with 2 approches like using below code in **Owner's** column.

```
editoptions:{                           
  dataEvents: [
      {
        type: 'change',
        fn: function(e) {
        modifyNotifyUsers(e);
        }
      }
    ]
},
```

And modifyNotifyUsers(e) somewhere written as

```
function modifyNotifyUsers(e){
  var userId = $(e.target).val();
  $.ajax({
      url:"getNotifiedUsersOnOwner.html?userId="+userId,
      type: "get",
      success:function(newOptions){
      var form = $(e.target).closest("form.FormGrid");
      $("select#notifyUsers.FormElement",form[0]).html(newOptions);
   }
 });
}
```

This approach is not working because, I think, I do not hvae `value` attribute in `editoptions` of **Owner** column. 
I tried using `dataUrl` also in `editopions` but my url is dynamic that's why I have to use `dataUrl` with `ondblClickRow()`

I tried calling simple jquery method on change of **Owner** dropdown like below.

```
$('#owner').change(function(){
     $('#searchcriteraigrid').setColProp('notifyUsers',{
      editoptions:{
         dataUrl:'getNotifiedUsersOnOwner.html?crit'+$('#criteriaId').val()
       }
  });
```

But this method call is also not happening. And the irony is, when I save my page as simple HTML and open that HTML in my browser then this method call happens. I can see by putting some alerts in method.

Could you please help me to get this working in any way or suggest me what and where I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it using below piece of code. I do not know what was the reasone that `.change()` not working but `.live('change')` worked. Later I made on ajx call and set my select box dynamically.

```
$('#owner').live('change', function() {
    var val = $('#owner').val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: 'getNotifiedUsersOnOwner.html?userId='+val,
          success: function(response) {                 
            $("#notifyUsers").html(response);
          }
       });
});
```

If you have any better way to do the same, please advice. Thanks

Comment: live has been deprecated in current jquery library

Comment: you may need to use .on function instead of live